# Flutter: Running flutter pub get in github actions with private dependencies

Tags: flutter, github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I'm using plugins that hosted privately in Github with an ssh access. When running `flutter pub get` in Github actions this command fails. I followed a tutorial that uses a deploy key and I tried this:

```
jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
        steps:
            -   uses: actions/checkout@v1

            -   name: Setup SSH Keys and known_hosts
                env:
                    SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh_agent.sock
                run: |
                    mkdir -p ~/.ssh
                    ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
                    ssh-agent -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK > /dev/null
                    ssh-add - <<< "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}"

            -   name: Some task that fetches dependencies
                env:
                    SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh_agent.sock
                run: flutter pub get
```

also tried:

```
  - uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.4.0
    with:
      ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
  - name: Fetch flutter dependencies
    run: flutter pub get
```

But the command still fails. What am I doing wrong and is there another way to make this command fetch private keys?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this action to add your ssh key.

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/install-ssh-key

Insert the private key and the known hosts in the secrets of your repository.

> NOTE: OPENSSH format (key begins with -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----) may not work due to OpenSSH version on VM. Please use PEM format (begins with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----) instead. In order to convert your key inline to PEM format simply use ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.

You can get the known hosts using:

```
ssh-keyscan github.com
```

After this add the ssh in your workflow:

```
- uses: shimataro/ssh-key-action@v2
    with:
      key: ${{ secrets.SSH }}
      name: id_rsa
      known_hosts: ${{ secrets.KNOWN_HOSTS }}
```

I hope this can help you